# azure application insight : troubleshoot size messages

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I like to troubleshoot the size of the message in app-insight.
Recently we've seen a big increase in data ingestion.

When I analyze the data ingestion I see that */- 90% of the size is taken by the "MESSAGE"

How can I see some examples of the MESSAGE content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `message` you mentioned is from `azure portal` -> `application insights` -> `Usage and estimated costs`, like screenshot below:

[image]

Then the `message` means the `traces telemetry data`. You can check the `traces telemetry data` from `azure portal` -> `application insights` -> `Logs` -> `traces` table, and write a simple query / select a proper `Time range` to check the details. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is to with increase in data ingestion at app insight, one of the things to check could be the sampling configuration which might be configured in the app using the app insight.

More info on sampling -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling